# Visualizer Disabled while using Battery Historian

Tags: performance, android-testing

I am facing problem while trying to visualize the graphs using Battery Historian in Android. I suspect the class causing the problem :

```
...class Printer(object)
```

`WARNING: Visualizer disabled. If you see this message, download the HTML then open it.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and found a connection is a must in order to get the graphical part of the report presented; 
thus you can either check if your windows firewall is blocking, or in my case mcafee firewall was blocking me on the timeline package by google. 
for Windows firewall unblock look at control panel/System and Security/Windows Firewall/Allowed Program (Server 2008).